# How do multiply a matrix?

Tags: c++, opengl, math

I know how multiply matrix, but my trouble is I don't know, whether need to multiply fourth row and fourth column, or they're standart. I mean, that I use to multiply only a matrix 3x3, and then I add a 4th row and 4th column, for that would it becomes a matrix 4x4.

If I have a matrix:

```
float *mat = new float[16];
/*
  0  1  2  3
  4  5  6  7
  8  9 10 11
 12 13 14 15
*/

//standart
mat[12] = mat[13] = mat[14] = mat[3] = mat[7] = mat[11] = 0.0f;
mat[15] = 1.0f;
```

But there are matrix of rotation, scaling and translation. How It work? Please, Could somebody to explain me? As well, we have an orthogonal or perspective matrix(matrix of projection).
**Total:**

- rotation matrix
- scaling matrix
- translation matrix
- projection matrix

And we have a point, for example `p[x,y,z]`. What happen further?

Comment: If you need to handle matrices for opengl, why not just use [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html) ?

Comment: Yes, you multiply the fourth row and column, take the sums, and the total becomes the corresponding placeholder. I''m not sure I understand the rest.

Comment: I use "Eigen", glm, but I want to learn and do this myself.

Comment: If we multiply matrix 4x4, for example identity matrix by rotation matrix(4x4), then we got invalid result in 3,7,11 elements or Not?

Comment: @Nawy If the rotated matrix has as many columns as the original does rows you will not receive a problem. In this case 4x4 rotated is still 4x4 so you will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

For a moment lets step back from multiplying matrices and lets look at how we multiply vectors with each other. There are two kinds of universally applicable vector product: The *inner* product (also called scalar product) and the *outer* product. (And then there's the cross product which only works for some kinds of vectors).

For the moment lets look at only the *inner* product. Let the inner product be defined as being the sum of the i-th column (`_`) with the i-th row (`^`) of each vector, if the first operand is a row vector

```
<a,b> = ∑ a_i b^i
```

or the i-th row with the i-th column if the first operand is a column vector by flipping their order

```
<a,b> = ∑ b_i a^i
```

For real numbers the reverse of order may seem arbitrary, but if you look at vectors of elements from a non-commutative group (and matrices are just that).

This of course requires to have the one vector to have as many columns as the other vector has rows. So lets say we have two *row* vectors **a** and **b**

```
a = (a1, a2, …, an)
b = (b1, b2, …, bn)
```

Obviously we can't multiply those in an *inner* product. But let's transpose one of them, to make a column, T(b) = b_, that works.

```
<a,b_> = a1 b1 + a2 b2 + … + an bn
```

So far so good.

Now lets look at matrix multiplication. If you look at a matrix you can see it as a column of row vectors

```
(11, 12, …, 1n)
(21, 22, …, 2n)
(…1, …2, …, …n)
(m1, m2, …, mn)
```

But that is just a column vector of row vectors!

```
/ (11, 12, …, 1n) \
| (21, 22, …, 2n) |
| (…1, …2, …, …n) |
\ (m1, m2, …, mn) /
```

or you can see it as a row of column vectors

```
/11\ /12\ /1…\ /1n\
|21| |22| |2…| |2n|
|…1| |…2| |……| |…n|
\m1/ \m2/ \m…/ \mn/
```

And of course this is just a row vector of column vectors

```
/ /11\ /12\ /1…\ /1n\ \
| |21| |22| |2…| |2n| |
| |…1| |…2| |……| |…n| |
\ \m1/ \m2/ \m…/ \mn/ /
```

So what happens of you try to put two matices through an inner product? `<A,B> = ?`. Well it turns out, that if A has as many rows as B has columns and B has as many rows as A has columns those two can get together if you look at A as a column of row vectors and B as a row of column vectors. What you then so is take the i-th row of A and take its inner product with each (j-th) column of B, writing the result at the ij location of the resulting matrix.

```
<A,B>_ij = <A^i,B_j>
```

Answer (score 0):

You multiply the 4x4 matrices as if they were matrices. The fourth row and column allow for homogeneous coordinates (with [x, y, z, w] corresponding to [x/w, y/w, z/w]), which allow translations to be represented as linear transformations. To apply this transformation to a point (x, y, z), left-multiply that matrix by the column vector [x, y, z, 1].